# HTML Not reading data from my github repository

Tags: javascript, html, github

I do have this github repository: 
https://github.com/silvestrep/SocialMediaGraphsVis

However, when I open the html I can't see the data: https://silvestrep.github.io/SocialMediaGraphsVis/index.html

Can anyone help me with this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was with the following line:

```
Index.html

...
d3.csv("../data/PadreHimalayaFollowersDatacsvpackage.csv"...
```

This is not the path to your csv file containing the data, and so the browser thought you were trying to access a remote resource and complained.

Change it to this instead:

```
Index.html

...
d3.csv("Data/PadreHimalayaFollowersDatacsvpackage.csv"...
```

Which is the correct path to your csv file.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah it was within those lines, actually ./ but thanks a lot, you pointed me to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Examining the page by using your browser's dev-tools, you will find an error like:

> uncaught exception: [object XMLHttpRequest]

The network-tab will tell you more details. In your case, the request to
`https://silvestrep.github.io/data/PadreHimalayaFollowersDatacsvpackage.csv`
results in **Error 404 (not found)**

Make sure you get the correct URL by navigating to the file in your repository and viewing it as "raw".

Then change the URL in your script to be `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silvestrep/SocialMediaGraphsVis/master/Data/PadreHimalayaFollowersDatacsvpackage.csv`